# Pandoc causes problem when knit .Rmd file (Raspbian)

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, r-markdown, pandoc

The purpose of the current project was to present good looking visualizations of participants' daily results after they filled in a questionnaire several times a day.

I decided to use R to compute the data and Rmarkdown to get the visualizations. This all should happen on a Raspberry Pi. I used a PHP file to create a .csv file (which contains participants' questionnaire data) on the webserver (Raspberry). This PHP file should also run an Rscript which in turn runs the rmarkdown command as follows:

```
rmarkdown::render(input = "Testplot.Rmd", output_file = paste0("results_", ID, ".html"), params = (list(ID = ID)))
```

So, if I run the Rscript manually (via SSH) everything runs as it should be and the results_ID.html is generated correctly.

The problem now is: If participants fill in the questionnaire and submit their data, the PHP file runs the Rscript using `exec("Rscript /var/www/html/cmdRmd.R, $ID")` and I always get this error message produced by Pandoc:

> Error in with_pandoc_safe_environment(system(paste(shQuote(path), "--version"),  : 
>     The 'HOME' environment variable must be set before running Pandoc.
>   Calls:  ... FUN -> get_pandoc_version -> with_pandoc_safe_environment.
>   Execution halted

My guess is that it has something to do with the www-data user of apache (which will be used when submitting data over the questionnaire). But I don't know how to set a 'HOME' environment variable for the www-data user.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: why don't you call pandoc as a commandline program directly? see https://pandoc.org... about the HOME maybe https://superuser.com/questions/271925/where-is-the-home-environment-variable-set

Answer (score 0):

You can set your environment within R like `Sys.setenv(HOME="/home/YOURHOME/"`. Make sure it corresponds to `echo $HOME` in your shell.